# What do the different coloured quests mean?

Tags: torchlight-2

When playing `Torchlight II`, I saw the quests were different colours.

[image: Active Quests panel]

What do the different colours mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **gold quests** are to do with the main story.

The **green quests** are side quests.